# Clear out individual variable in SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have the following `SharedPreference` being saved in my app:

```
editor.putString("strInfName", nameOfInf.getText().toString());
editor.putFloat("dblTollAmount", Float.parseFloat(tollAmount.getText().toString()));
```

How do i just clear out only one variable instead of both?

`editor.clear();` would clear out all variables but I am only looking to clear out, `strInfName` only.

Would this work:

```
editor.edit().remove("strInfName").commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29):

> public abstract SharedPreferences.Editor remove (String key)
>
> Added in API level 1 Mark in the editor that a preference value should
>   be removed, which will be done in the actual preferences once commit()
>   is called.
>
> Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals are
>   done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after
>   put methods on this editor.
>
> Parameters key    The name of the preference to remove. Returns Returns a
>   reference to the same Editor object, so you can chain put calls
>   together.

Comment: @SiKni8 - an important part of finding the right method to call is to read and understand the documentation. Does the documentation that he quoted do what you want? Then it is probably the right method.

Comment: `editor.remove("strInfName"); NOT WORKING` I am using Fragment to save for the data to be used in another tab.